# Set last date before save angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to change date value before save. according to my requirement, i need to set last date of the month before save. this is my save function

```
     $scope.saveCashBenefits = function (a) {
            var olddate = $scope.newcashbenifit.toDate;
            //for an example olddate = Wed Apr 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530

        }
```

In the above sample, the `olddate` is 'Wed Apr 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530'
I need to modify this as 'Apr 30 2020'

if `olddate` is Month 'May', I need to set my month as 'May 31 2020'

basically i need to set last day of the month.

How I do it?

Comment: found the solution

Comment: var olddate = $scope.newcashbenifit.toDate;
                var date = $scope.newcashbenifit.toDate;
                var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

Comment: please answer *your own question* for future users